# deploying AKS cluster with AGIC and managed identity through Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-aks

I am attempting to deploy an AKS cluster with AGIC ingress controller using Terraform. One of the requirements is that all the Identities that are involved in functioning of that cluster must be User-Assigned (no identity should be created "automatically" by Azure).

So far I have created the following components:

```
// User-Assigned Managed IDs for AGW, cluster, and kubelets

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "my_agw_id" {
    (...)
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "my_cluster_id" {
    (...)
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "my_kubelet_id" {
    (...)
}

// Application Gateway

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "my_agw" {
    
    (...)
    
    identity {
        type         = "UserAssigned"
        identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.my_agw_id.id]
  }
    
}

// AKS cluster

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  
  (...)

  node_resource_group = "my_node_rg"

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
    network_policy = "azure"
  }

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.my_cluster_id.id]
  }

  kubelet_identity {
    client_id                 = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.my_kubelet_id.client_id
    object_id                 = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.my_kubelet_id.principal_id
    user_assigned_identity_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.my_kubelet_id.id
  }

  ingress_application_gateway {
    gateway_id = azurerm_application_gateway.my_agw.id
  }

}
```

Now, this works fine, but in addition to the 3 UAMIs I have created myself, the AGIC creates additional UAMI in the "my_node_rg", called "ingressapplicationgateway...". As far as I understand this ID is required for AGIC plugin to be able to amend Application Gateway Settings when Kubernetes ingress object is created, and that makes sense. My question is - how can I create this AGIC UAMI myself, and then assign it to AGIC during creation of the cluster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to confirm this is not supported at the moment.

It looks like the Azure ARM templates were supposed to include this functionality at some point (https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2374), and it was requested to update Terraform azurerm provider to leverage this (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/21008). Unfortunately, in the end ARM only supports the BYO UAMI in the ARM schema, but this input is disregarded.